# how to use android material button for android 4 and above?

Tags: android

I'm trying to add simple button on my layout, my min api is 14, The problem is when run the app on android < 5.0 the button doesn't have any animation , How can I fix that?

Comment: check out this tutorial.
http://www.androidumps.com/pages/article_002/chapter1.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the animation you are talking about is Ripple Effect. That is a feature of material design. And remember the official material design theme is supported for android >= 5.0.

I guess that you are using default theme. So, when you run your app on android 5.0 or above it will using material theme (with ripple effect for button). However, when you run android < 5.0, the theme now is not material theme and button doesn't have ripple effect.

For solve your problem, you need using third party libraries to apply material design to your app. Here is list of awesome ui library and you can find some libraries that help you applying material design.

The list of awesome ui library: https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui

Comment: I don't want to fix this with 3rd party library , is it possible to fix this with android design library?

Comment: No, currently, we don't have any way to fix it without using 3rd party library.